# CEWP blocked access to SP pages

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, css, cewp

While I was working on my department SP 2013 page and trying to modify a Gantt view list with a piece of css placed in hidden CEWP. I saved the page and the browser showed a blank white page, not only the page with the CEWP but all subsites and etc. 
I have tried to access the page in maintenance mode with ?content=1 but it doesn't help me out.
Any suggestions how to remove be faulty CEWP and to access the pages?

Answer (score 0):

Try SharePoint Designer with the following steps...

1. Open the site in SharePoint Designer
2. Click on "All Files" folder from left navigation menu.
3. Navigate to the list where you have that listview.
4. Open the specific listview page which showed blank in browser.
5. Find the CEWP under ContentPlaceHolder "PlaceHolderMain"...remove that webpart or change your css.
6. Save the page.

This will restore the page in previous state.